# How to prevent keyboard moving up an other widget in a stack? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've got a new transaction screen with several textfields and a container at the bottom for shortcuts:

[image: a stack with a column of textfields and a grey Container below]

And when i trigger a textfield the grey container moves up as well:
[image: grey container moves up as well and overlap the textfield when i Tap the last one ,,notes'']

Here is my code for the screen:

```js
//import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

//import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../items/icon_picket_item.dart';
import '../items/select_transaction_item.dart';

import '../providers/user_transactions.dart';
import '../providers/icon_auswahl.dart';
import '../providers/account_type.dart';
import '../providers/user_settings/single_multiple_acc.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../storag/locale.dart';
import '../storag/foundation.dart';

import '../my_icons.dart';

class NewTransactionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/new-transaction';
  @override
  _NewTransactionScreenState createState() => _NewTransactionScreenState();
}

class _NewTransactionScreenState extends State<NewTransactionScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final _titleController = TextEditingController(text: '');
  final _amountController = TextEditingController(text: '-10.00');
  final _accountController = TextEditingController();
  final _notesController = TextEditingController();
  final _repeatController = TextEditingController();

  DateTime _selectedDate;
  Color _correct = Colors.white54;
  final data = [];

  void _colorCorrect() {
    final enteredTitle = _titleController.text;
    final enteredAmount = _amountController.text;
    final enteredAccount = _accountController.text;
    final enteredRepeat = _repeatController.text;

    Color color;

    if (enteredTitle.isEmpty ||
        enteredAmount.isEmpty ||
        enteredAccount.isEmpty ||
        enteredRepeat.isEmpty) {
      color = Colors.white54;
    } else {
      color = Colors.white;
    }

    setState(() {
      _correct = color;
    });
  }

  void _submitData(String choiceId, NewTransactions transactions, iconData,
      GeldKonto kontoss) {
    //onSubmitted gives you a string
    if (_amountController.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    final enteredTitle = _titleController.text;
    final enteredAmount = _amountController.text;
    final enteredAccount = _accountController.text;
    final enteredNotes = _notesController.text;
    final enteredRepeat = _repeatController.text;
    Icon enteredIcon = iconData.taken;

    if (enteredTitle.isEmpty ||
        enteredAmount.isEmpty ||
        enteredAccount.isEmpty ||
        enteredRepeat.isEmpty) {
      return; //means code stops here and addTx doesnt run
    } else {
      transactions.addNewtransaction(
          xTitle: enteredTitle,
          xAmount: double.parse(enteredAmount) <= 0
              ? double.parse(enteredAmount) * (-1)
              : double.parse(enteredAmount),
          xchosenDate: _selectedDate == null ? DateTime.now() : _selectedDate,
          xAccountType: enteredAccount,
          xNotes: enteredNotes,
          xRepeat: enteredRepeat,
          xIcon: enteredIcon,
          xId: DateTime.now().toString(),
          xchoiceId: choiceId);
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop(context);
    // .pop closes modalsheet , you have the property contexyt cause of extends state
  }

  Container _buildTransactionRow(
      {Text typedText,
      Function onPress,
      comparisonStuff,
      Icon icon,
      double iconSpace,
      double iconAfterSpace}) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Container(
      // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 15),
      child: Row(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 1, width: iconSpace),
          icon,
          SizedBox(height: 1, width: iconAfterSpace), //25
          SizedBox(
            width: mediaQuery.size.width * 0.75,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: onPress,
              child: Column(
                //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 17, width: 1),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: mediaQuery.size.width * 0.75,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                          width: 4,
                        ),
                        typedText
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10, width: mediaQuery.size.width * 0.04),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 1,
                    width: mediaQuery.size.width * 0.75,
                    child: const Divider(
                      color: Colors.white54,
                      thickness: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAppBar(String pageTitle, NewTransactions transactions,
      GeldKonto kontoss, String choiceId) {
    return AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      leading: isIos == true
          ? IconButton(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.back, size: 30, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(context),
            )
          : IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, size: 30, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(context),
            ),
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        pageTitle,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Consumer<IconAuswahl>(
          builder: (ctx, iconData, child) => IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
              start: 15,
              end: 25,
              top: 5,
              bottom: 0,
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              MyIcon.correct,
              size: 45,
              color: _correct,
            ),
            onPressed: () =>
                _submitData(choiceId, transactions, iconData, kontoss),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffb00374a),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildColumn(
      BuildContext context, AppBar appBar, local, String choiceId) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

    return Stack(children: <Widget>[

      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            end: Alignment.topCenter,
            colors: [Colors.black, Color(0xffb00374a)],
          ),
        ),
      ),
       Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
            color: Colors.grey),
      ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                  appBar.preferredSize.height -
                  mediaQuery.padding.top ) * 1.05 ,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10,
            left: 20,
            right: 10,
            bottom:0,
                //
                 // so that the whole thing always move +10
          ),
          child: Consumer<SinlgeOrMultiple>(
              builder: (_, data, __) => data.multipleAcc == true
                  ? Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                          // CupertinoTextField(

                          // ),
                          _buildTransactionRow(
                              comparisonStuff: _selectedDate,
                              typedText: Text(
                                  _selectedDate == null
                                      ? 'Bankkonto'
                                      : 'Mein Ausgewähltes Zeug',
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
                              icon: const Icon(MyIcon.account, size: 38),
                              iconSpace: 3,
                              iconAfterSpace: 20,
                              onPress: () {}),

                          Row(children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(width: 3.5),
                            choiceId == '0'
                                ? const Icon(
                                    MyIcon.paying,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 25,
                                  )
                                : const Icon(
                                    MyIcon.earning,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 43,
                                  ),
                         const   SizedBox(width: 33),
                            SelectTransactionItem(
                                choiceId == '0' //id of new outcome
                                    ? '-${oCcyy.format(0)}'
                                    : '${oCcyy.format(0)}',
                                _amountController,
                                false,
                                _colorCorrect),
                          ]),

                          Row(
                           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconPicked(_scaffoldKey, choiceId),
                            const  SizedBox(
                                  width:
                                     14),
                              SelectTransactionItem(
                                  'Titel',
                                  _titleController,
                                  true,
                                  _colorCorrect),
                                 
                            ],
                          ),

                          _buildTransactionRow(
                              comparisonStuff: _selectedDate,
                              typedText: Text(
                                  _selectedDate == null
                                      ? 'Jede 2 Woche'
                                      : 'Ausgewählter Stuff',
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
                              icon: const Icon(MyIcon.runningtime, size: 40),
                              iconSpace: 0,
                              iconAfterSpace: 20,
                              onPress: () {}),

                          _buildTransactionRow(
                            comparisonStuff: _selectedDate,
                            typedText: Text(
                                _selectedDate == null
                                    ? '${DateFormat.yMd(local).format(DateTime.now())}'
                                    : '${DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate)}',
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
                            icon: const Icon(MyIcon.calender, size: 39),
                            iconSpace: 3,
                            iconAfterSpace: 18,
                            onPress: () {
                              showModalBottomSheet(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext builder) {
                                    return SizedBox(
                                      height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                              .copyWith()
                                              .size
                                              .height /
                                          3,
                                      child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                        //backgroundColor: Color(0xffb00374a),
                                        initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                                        onDateTimeChanged:
                                            (DateTime pickedDate) {
                                          if (pickedDate == null) {
                                            return;
                                          }
                                          setState(() {
                                            _selectedDate = pickedDate;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        // use24hFormat: true,
                                        maximumDate: DateTime.now(),
                                        minimumYear: 2010,
                                        maximumYear: 2020,
                                        //minuteInterval: 1,
                                        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  });
                            },
                          ),

                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                            const  SizedBox(width: 3.5),
                            const  Icon(
                                MyIcon.notes,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 37,
                              ),
                           const   SizedBox(width: 20),
                              SelectTransactionItem('Notizen', _notesController,
                                  false, _colorCorrect),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Container(
            width: 0.1,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
            color: Colors.transparent),
                        ])
                  : Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                          
                         
                          Row(children: <Widget>[
                           const  SizedBox(width: 3.5),
                            choiceId == '0'
                                ? const Icon(
                                    MyIcon.paying,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 25,
                                  )
                                : const Icon(
                                    MyIcon.earning,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 43,
                                  ),
                          const  SizedBox(width: 33),
                            SelectTransactionItem(
                                choiceId == '0' //id of new outcome
                                    ? '-${oCcyy.format(0)}'
                                    : '${oCcyy.format(0)}',
                                _amountController,
                                false,
                                _colorCorrect),
                          ]),

                          Row(
                           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconPicked(_scaffoldKey, choiceId),
                            const  SizedBox(
                                  width:
                                     14),
                              SelectTransactionItem(
                                  'Titel',
                                  _titleController,
                                  true,
                                  _colorCorrect),
                                 
                            ],
                          ),

                          _buildTransactionRow(
                              comparisonStuff: _selectedDate,
                              typedText: Text(
                                  _selectedDate == null
                                      ? 'Jede 2 Woche'
                                      : 'Ausgewählter Stuff',
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
                              icon: const Icon(MyIcon.runningtime, size: 40),
                              iconSpace: 0,
                              iconAfterSpace: 20,
                              onPress: () {}),

                          _buildTransactionRow(
                            comparisonStuff: _selectedDate,
                            typedText: Text(
                                _selectedDate == null
                                    ? '${DateFormat.yMd(local).format(DateTime.now())}'
                                    : '${DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate)}',
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
                            icon: const Icon(MyIcon.calender, size: 39),
                            iconSpace: 3,
                            iconAfterSpace: 18,
                            onPress: () {
                              showModalBottomSheet(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext builder) {
                                    return SizedBox(
                                      height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                              .copyWith()
                                              .size
                                              .height /
                                          3,
                                      child:  CupertinoDatePicker(
                                        //backgroundColor: Color(0xffb00374a),
                                        initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                                        onDateTimeChanged:
                                            (DateTime pickedDate) {
                                          if (pickedDate == null) {
                                            return;
                                          }
                                          setState(() {
                                            _selectedDate = pickedDate;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        // use24hFormat: true,
                                        maximumDate: DateTime.now(),
                                        minimumYear: 2010,
                                        maximumYear: 2020,
                                        //minuteInterval: 1,
                                        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  });
                            },
                          ),

                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                           const   SizedBox(width: 3.5),
                             const Icon(
                                MyIcon.notes,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 37,
                              ),
                            const  SizedBox(width: 20),
                              SelectTransactionItem('Notizen', _notesController,
                                  false, _colorCorrect),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Container(
            width: 0.1,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
            color: Colors.transparent),
                        ])),
        ),
      ),
    
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var local = Localizations.localeOf(context).toString();
    final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final _pageTitle = routeArgs['pageTitle'];
    final _choiceId = routeArgs['id'];
    final transactions = Provider.of<NewTransactions>(context, listen: false);

    final kontoss = Provider.of<GeldKonto>(context, listen: false);

    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar =
        _buildAppBar(_pageTitle, transactions, kontoss, _choiceId);

    return
        // SafeArea(
        //       child:
        Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: appBar,

      // body: Stack(
      //   children: <Widget>[

      body: _buildColumn(context, appBar, local, _choiceId),

      //),
    );
  }
}
```

It is fine when i open the upper textfield but the container overlap when opening the last textfield. I can scroll up to see the notes ,,textfield'', but it looks ugly when I open the notes ,,textfield'' and the thing is overlapping. Is there a way to move the textfield up automatically or just preventing that the Container is pushed up as well?

I tried to put the padding of the textfield column Container to + 10, but it squeezed the whole page.

`padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10,
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 
                10, // so that the whole thing always move +10
          ),`

Do you have any advice to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping Scaffold widget with a Stack and then put the Container widget after Scaffod

Comment: This is a good idea, thanks. It works almost, but the problem is if you want to put some buttons like iconbuttons in the container. That is not possible without a material widget ancestor. Do you know how to that without wrapping the container into a scaffold, (because with scaffold the other scaffold can not be seen)

Comment: I sovlved it :). I wrapet my Container from the textfields with a column and put the grey Container under textfield Container, so that both elements are located in  the Single Child scroll View widget

Answer (score 14):

Try adding `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to your scaffold

Answer (score 4):

If you need to hide some widgets when keyboard is visible, you can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility

Example:

```
KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(builder: (context, isKeyboardVisible) {
        return isKeyboardVisible
            ? const SizedBox()
            : const MyButton();
      }),
```

I don't like using `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false`, because, when you have a text field, it doesn't allow to move the text field to the top of keyboard.